# Docker problem with symbol like ' | ' in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: docker, cmd

I'm using Docker for containers and Windows for development. I have a container with Ubuntu Linux on the container, I'm executing the command

`docker exec -u 0  project-0 bash -c 'echo developer_1:test123 | chpasswd'`

but windows thinking like I'm executing `chpasswd`, windows don't have that command and I have the error. How to fix it?

I tried a lot of methods to beat this problem, but all unsuccessful. Maybe something wrong with my command?

Comment: What's your host shell? CMD, PowerShell or bash?

Comment: CMD and tried PowerShell.Both failed.

Comment: you can escape it with the circumflex accent `^` in cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape character in CMD is `^`:

```
docker exec -u 0  project-0 bash -c 'echo developer_1:test123 ^| chpasswd'
```

Alternatively, you can use double quotes:

```
docker exec -u 0  project-0 bash -c "echo developer_1:test123 | chpasswd"
```

Comment: Minute.I will try it.

Comment: Method 0 - Failed.
[developer_1:test123: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
developer_1:test123: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file]
Method 1 - Success.Thanks